# OpenDJ fresh install giving 403 Insufficient Access

Tags: access-rights, opendj

I have just completed a fresh install of OpenDJ and I have loaded the Example.ldif provided as a test case. Following their examples provided I am trying to use the [OpenDJ restful](http://opendj.forgerock.org/opendj-server/doc/admin-guide/index/chap-rest-operations.html) operations found here:

I enabled HTTP access on port 8080 and OpenDJ is running.

I performed the GET operation just fine. It returned the user information for bjensen. However, when I try the PUT example using kvaughan I receive the following error:

> {"code":403,"reason":"Forbidden","message":"Insufficient Access Rights: The entry uid=newuser,ou=people,dc=example,dc=com cannot be added due to insufficient access rights"}

Any operation to add or edit information through a RESTful operation is unsuccessful.

EDIT:

I just got it to work by creating the baseDN and importing Example.ldif on create instead of importing at a later time through the control panel.

I guess my new question is, what causes the difference?

Answer (score 0):

By default in OpenDJ, in order to make it ease to get started, anonymous access is enabled for read only operations, and the REST interface then allow to do GET.
As soon as you want to do LDAP updates or PUT (through the REST interface), you need to authenticate as a user who has the permissions to Add or Modify entries.